# MVVMCross: Xamarin iOS - Passing VM object during navigation

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Can we pass ViewModel object during navigation in MVVMCross? I am trying to pass view model object but on the navigated page its returning null even though I could see that the object I sent was not null.

**ViewModel 1:**

```
private void DoEditPhoto(int imageNum)
{
     ShowViewModel<ViewModel2>(new { index = Index,vm = this });
}
```

**ViewModel 2:**

```
private int index;
ViewModel1 vm;

public void Init(int index, ViewModel1 vm)
        {
            this.index = index;
            this.vm = vm as ViewModel1;
        }
```

In the Init func on VIewModel2 i tried changing the second parameter from ViewModel1 to Object, but its not able to receive the object, I am sending from the navigated page.

Can anyone please advice ?

Comment: This should only be used to pass small and simple values. Not entire models.

Comment: I need to raise `RaisePropertyChange` for some of the properties on vm1 if vm2 does some operations. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @AzharAli That's an entirely different question. But what you could do is to use `Events` or the `IMvxMessenger`